# how to include a javascript file in the layout

Tags: layout

I want to add a custom js file. So I added

`<action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/load.js</name></action>`

in

`app/design/frontend/package_name/theme_name/layout/page.xml`

and added that js file into

`skin/frontend/package_name/theme_name/js/load.js`

But the javascript is not working. Kindly someone guide me.

Comment: Can you please put full `page.xml` file here?

Comment: Its a fresh magento theme. In that I just added the above line alone.

Comment: Yes but i want to know where you added this line. So please share it

Comment: please share your page.xml code here where you had written this code

Answer (score 1):

**Scenario 1:**

Make sure you added your line inside the `<block>` if you are modyfing the `page.xml` file.

Example:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
...
<default>
  ...
  <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
    ...
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/load.js</name></action>
    ...
  </block >
  ...
</default>
...
</layout>
```

**Scenario 2:**

If you have a custom XML file add in a `<reference name="head">`.

Make sure you added in `<default>` handler if you like to have it in all your pages.

Example:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
...
<default>
  ...
  <reference name="head">
    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/load.js</name></action>
  </reference>
  ...
</default>
...
</layout>
```

If you have a custom layout XML file make sure you added in your module `config.xml` file as follows:

```
<config>
    ...
    <frontend>
        ...
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <my_module>
                    <file>my_module.xml</file>
                </my_module>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        ...
    </frontend>
    ...
</config>
```

Also make sure there are no XML errors. Magento will not display you any error, it will just ignore your custom XML file.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You have specify the handle.

If you want to add the js files for all page use default handle. i.e.

```
<default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addJs"><type>skin_js</type>name>js/load.js</name></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

Comment: shall i use it in same page.xml file?

Comment: better do all of your changes in new created local.xml file inside layout directory. E.g. app/desing/frontend/base/default/layout/local.xml

Comment: Yes that would be good practice. But the above could will definitely work

Comment: No. It is not working. When I give the script directly in the phtml file it is working. When I give it in page.xml it is not working. Also I tried creating local.xml. That too failed

Comment: Did you do any other changes then?

Comment: No. I just copied your above code into my page.xml

Answer (score 0):

Your page.xml should look like below.

```
 <default>
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/load.js</name></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

**OR**

> create new xml file called "local.xml" at
>   app/design/frontend/package_name/theme_name/layout/

and put below code in that and check result. i hope this will work for you

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="1.0.0.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/load.js</name></action>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: i gave but no change

Comment: Okay. Now Just view source of you html page and check url of that js file exist or not ?

Comment: just view source and search for "load.js" word. if you found this line then your xml is working fine and js path is wrong

Comment: No I dont find the 'load.js' file

Comment: then make sure your xml is correct in term of syntax . check for any log in system.log file

Comment: and don't forget to clear cache from admin + your browser cache

Comment: i have updated my answer

Comment: No I tried everything as per your guidance. Can you guess where have I went wrong? As you mentioned above am unable to see load.js when I view the page source.

Comment: create new xml file called "local.xml" at app/design/frontend/package_name/theme_name/layout/

Comment: updated my answer again please follow second way and check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36162/discussion-between-ramya-and-minesh-patel).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the js file in not getting included.
Try using below code in page.xml or local.xml -

```
<default>
  <reference name="head">
    <action method="addJs"><script>theme_name/yourfile.js</script></action>
  </reference>
</default>
```

Make sure you create folder in "root/js/theme_name/" and add your js file there.